# Applying styles to old document with lots of problems in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

At work I frequently need to format documents that others have edited.  Usually a document has been drafted by multiple people on different computers so the formatting is a mess.  When I get the document, I need to clean everything up and apply some standardized styles.  What is the best way to do this?  I've been simply going line by line to select text (paragraphs, headings, etc. as appropriate) and applying the appropriate style.  Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool is to SaveAs and select [RTF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725) [2](http://accessproject.colostate.edu/udl/modules/word/tut_rtf.cfm) [3](http://interglacial.com/rtf/), which retains most formatting, but strips away Word's history of change upon change upon change. Close the document, read in the RTF file, SaveAs DOCX with a name change, and then apply your uniform styles.